# Is this relation antisymmetric, connex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

> Given is relation  $R=\left\{(a,b) \in S \times S: a+b \text{ is an
> even number }\right\}$ over the set $S=\mathbb{N}$. Is this relation
>   antisymmetric, connex? Justify your decision.

A relation is antisymmetric if $\forall x,y \in A: xRy \wedge yRx \Rightarrow x=y$

A relation is connex, if $\forall x,y \in A: (x,y) \in R \vee (y,x) \in R $ or $x=y$

The sum of two numbers is even if and only if both summands are even or both summands are odd.

**antisymmetric:** If we have $aRb$, then both summands are either even or odd, same applies for $bRa$. Buth now the implication says $x=y$, so we might end up with an odd number which means that this relation is not antisymmetric.

**connex:** If we concentrate at the 3th condition of connexivity, i.e. $x=y$, then we will end up with an even number because both summands will either be even or uneven and thus the sum will be even. So the relation is connex.

---

This task was confusing me a lot.. I'm pretty sure that this relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive but I'm not sure about these two properties. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addition is commutative. So, $(2,4)\in R$ and $(4,2)\in R$. Then $R$ is not antisymmetric.

The second condition: $(2,3)\not\in R$ and $(3,2)\not\in R$ and $2\ne 3$. The relation is not connex.

Comment: BTW: the relation in question is symmetric. Which relation $\rho$ on a set $A$ is both symmetric and antisymmetric? Let $(x,y)\in\rho$. By symmetry $(y,x)\in\rho$. Then by antisymmetry $x=y$ and $\rho$ is the equality relation on some subset $B\subset A$.

Comment: But how can be $(2,3) \in R$ if the sum of it is odd?

Comment: I have misread the definition. I considered odd sum. Thanks - I corrected the answer. It was enough to switch the examples.

Comment: Ok thank you :) For showing the relation is not connex, you have used summands whose sum is odd. Thus they do not belong to $R$. Would your example really show that this relation is not connex then?

Comment: Yes, of course. Examine the connexity condition by its negation.